How do I center the body tag of the website
I'm trying to build a responsive website. The problem is that whenever the width of screen size is under 800, the body tag stay on the left like in this image, otherwise it stay in the center of the website. I want it to stay in the center in both cases. Can someone help me out please? Thank you.
body {
    background-color: #F8F7FE;
    font-family: "Baloo Da 2", sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

/* begin of header's css */
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    border-top: 1px rgb(179, 177, 177) solid;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px rgba(184, 53, 210, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-button-group {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.right-button-group {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.subButton {
    width: 155px;
    height: 60px;
    border: none;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.subButton a {
    color: #292D34;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 23px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.subButton:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.logo {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #7B68EE;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #a396eb;}


.dropdown-content-button {
    top:60px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content-button a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {    /* Change layout for larger screens */
    .dropdown {
        display: none;   /* Change to horizontal */
    }
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {    /* Change layout for larger screens */
    .left-button-group, .right-button-group {
        display: none;   /* Change to horizontal */
    }
    .header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
}

/* end of header's css */
.head-of-main{
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 70px;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: space-around;
}
.page-title {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #45C4F9 0%, #7D09FF 50%, #FF0BE5 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.page-description {
    margin: 0;
    width: 600px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
}

/* begin of wrapper's css */
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 40vh;
    gap: 70px;
}

.box {
    width: 350px;
    height: 490px;
    top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #a396eb;
    background-color: #F5EEFC;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.form-title {
    color: #7B68EE; 
    font-size: 25px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.box .button-create,
.box .link {
    margin: 25px 0;
}

.input {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 19px 25px rgba(41, 45, 52, 0.04); */
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.input input {
    height: 30px;
    border: 0.5px solid grey;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 260px;
}
.input ::placeholder {
    color: #757575; 
    font-size: 15px; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.input select {
    color: #757575;
    width: 265px;
    height: 33px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 19px 25px rgba(41, 45, 52, 0.04);
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 1px #B9BEC7 solid;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.input-shapes::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 23px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 0;
    background: url('{% static "/winking.png" %}');
    cursor: pointer;
}

.input-shapes::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 23px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 0;
    background: url('contrasticon.png');
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ans-no-ans {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

input[type='radio'] {
    size: 10px;
}

#create {
    width: 100px;
}
#create-with-answer {
    width: 200px;
}

.img {
    position: relative;
    width: 515px;
    height: 617px;
    right: 20%;
    top: 225px;
    transform: translateX(20%);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.download-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25%;
    top: 880px;
    background: #7B68EE; 
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px rgba(123, 104, 238, 0.50);
    width: 150px; 
    height: 40px; 
    border-radius: 9px;
    text-align: center; 
    color: white; 
    font-size: 18px; 
    font-weight: 700; 
    line-height: 21px; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: none;
}

.download-button:hover {
    background: #a396eb;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {    /* Change layout for larger screens */
    .wrapper {
        flex-direction: column;   /* Change to horizontal */
    }
    .box {
        top: 20px;
    }
    .img {
        top: 0px;
    }
}
/* end of wrapper's css */

.show1 {display:block;}

.line {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.show2 {display:block;}


my code html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale1.0"> 
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Da+2:wght@400..800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static '/favicon.ico' %}">
    <!-- add version=1 to resolve cache issue -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{%static '/wordsearch.css' %}?version=1"> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="left-button-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
      <button type="button" class="subButton"><a href="home">Home</a></button>
      <button type="button" class="subButton"><a href="guide">Guide to use</a></button>
    </div>
    <img class="logo" src="{% static '/logoWS.jpg' %}" alt="logo">
    <div class="right-button-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
      <button type="button" class="subButton"><a href="about_us">About us</a></button>
      <button type="button" class="subButton"><a href="logout">Log out</a></button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">&#9776;</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="home">Home</a>
        <a href="guide">Guide to use</a>
        <a href="about_us">About us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="head-of-main">
    <h1 class="page-title">AI-Powered Word Search Game</h1>
    <p class="page-description">
        This interactive game integrates AI technology to create engaging word search puzzles tailored to your lesson plans, improving vocabulary in a fun way.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <form method='POST' action="generate">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2 class="form-title">What lesson is this for ?</h2>
        <div class="input">
          <div class="input-subject">
            <label>Subject<br>
              <input name='course' type="text" placeholder=" e.g. Math" required>
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-lesson">
            <label>Lesson name<br>
              <input name='lesson' type="text" placeholder=" e.g. Pytago" required>
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-grade">
            <label>Grade level<br>
              <input name='grade' type="text" placeholder=" e.g. Grade 9" required>
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- shapes: Circle, Club, Dimiond, Donut, Fish, Flower, Heart, Hexagon, Octagon, Pentagon, Spade, Star5, Star6 -->
          <!-- Star8, Tree, Triangle -->
          <div class="input-shapes">
            <label>Shapes</label><br>
            <select name="shapes" id="dropdownMenuCreate" class="dropdownMenuCreate">
              <option value="circle" class="shapes">Circle</option>
              <option value="club" class="shapes">Club</option>
              <option value="dimiond" class="shapes">Dimiond</option>
              <option value="donut" class="shapes">Donut</option>
              <option value="fish" class="shapes">Fish</option>
              <option value="flower" class="shapes">Flower</option>
              <option value="heart" class="shapes">Heart</option>
              <option value="hexagon" class="shapes">Hexagon</option>
              <option value="octagon" class="shapes">Octagon</option>
              <option value="pentagon" class="shapes">Pentagon</option>
              <option value="spade" class="shapes">Spade</option>
              <option value="star5" class="shapes">Star with 5 edges</option>
              <option value="star6" class="shapes">Star with 6 edges</option>
              <option value="star8" class="shapes">Star with 8 edges</option>
              <option value="tree" class="shapes">Tree</option>
              <option value="triangle" class="shapes">Triangle</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <!-- 8 levels -->
          <div class="input-level">
            <input type="range" min="1" max = "8" value='1' class="level-bar" id="game-level" name="level-bar" placeholder="e.g. level 1">
          </div>
          <!-- <button type="button" class="button-create" id="create" onclick="toggleDropdownCreate()">Create</button> -->
          <div class="ans-no-ans">
              <label for="ans">
                Answer<br>
                <input type="radio" id="ans" name='create-options'value="Answer">
              </label>
              <label for="no-ans">
                No Answer<br>
                <input type="radio" id="no-ans" name='create-options' value="No Answer">
              </label>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="button" id="create"/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="image-display">
      {% if image %}
        <img class="img" src="{{media_url}}{{image}}" alt="logo">
      {% else %}
        <img class="img" src="{% static '/imageWS.jpg' %}" alt="logo">
      {% endif %}
      {% if pdf_filename %}
        <form method="get" action="{% url 'download' pdf_filename %}">
            <button class="download-button" type='submit'>Download PDF</button>
        </form>
      {% else %}
      {% endif %}
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
  var output = document.getElementById("demo");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

  // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
  function toggleDropdownCreate() {
    var dropdownMenuCreate = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuCreate");
    dropdownMenuCreate.classList.toggle("show2");
  }
  function toggleDropdown() {
    var dropdownMenu = document.getElementById("dropdownMenu");
    dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("show1");
  }
  
  // Đóng dropdown menu nếu click ra ngoài
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.button-avatar')) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content-button");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show1')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show1');
        }
      }
    }
    if (!event.target.matches('.button-create')) {
      var dropdownsCreate = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content-button-create");
      var j;
      for (j = 0; j < dropdownsCreate.length; j++) {
        var openDropdownCreate = dropdownsCreate[j];
        if (openDropdownCreate.classList.contains('show2')) {
          openDropdownCreate.classList.remove('show2');
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>



Looks like it may need more of the CSS to be able to identify the issue. If you want them stacked on top of each other you could try display: flex; flex-direction: column, but there's plenty of ways styles on other elements could prevent that from working.

whats the effective (computed) body css?

@l3l_aze, hi there, I have add all of my css, can you help me here, I have tried display: flex; flex-direction: column but the body element still stay on the left

@PerdiEstaquel, do you mean this link

Can you edit your question and add a fiddle so we could test your problem on this page?

To adjust your layout for screen sizes below 800px, you can use the following media queries:
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* CSS adjustments for screen widths up to 600px */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* CSS adjustments for screen widths of 600px and above */
}

Within these media queries, you can apply specific CSS rules to handle layout changes, such as centering elements or making other adjustments as needed.
Hope that helps :)
